# Уже и не знаю(,) что и поделать

Tags: запятые

Почему в предложении *Я не знаю, что ей подарить* нужна запятая, но в предложении *Уже и не знаю что и поделать* — не нужна?

Comment: Скобки с запятой с пробелом, см.: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=182.

Comment: Все пишут без пробела. Можете доказать, почему нужен пробел?  Только без правил, а по смыслу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше так: *Уж не знаю **что И поделать**.*

Запятая не ствится при наличии союза И по правилу **[Розенталя, пункт 4(2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)**

4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится: 2) если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз И:  *Не представлял себе **и как** выбраться из создавшегося положения; Я знаю **и как** это делается; Мальчика прощали **и когда** он никого не слушался.*

Здесь союз И **инверсированный** и является скорее **усилительной** частицей.

Сравнить: *Уж не знаю **И что поделать**.*